# How smooth should I expect final finish to be on an new hardwood floor install?

Tags: floor, hardwood, hardwood-refinishing

I had an existing hardwood floor in one part of the first floor connected to new wood in the rest of the first floor. The contractor has done a great job of splicing in so there is no gap. What I'm wondering is how smooth should I expect the final finish to be? After three finish coats, there are still some bumps in the finish. It is all over, not just these three images [image][image][image]

Comment: I'm personally very interested in the answers, but this is opinion based which is not how this site works  (I'm not the one that flagged it)

Comment: Looks more like there are things that fell on the floor while the finish was drying (the hair in 2nd pic and fluff in 3rd) than that it wasn't "smooth". You don't want your floor to be mirror smooth - it'll be like walking on ice if your feet/shoes are the least bit damp.

Comment: If you care enough about it, lightly sand out the bumps and debris with >200 grit sandpaper, then apply another coat. That said, nobody but you will ever notice such imperfections; they are barely visible in carefully-selected close up photos.

Comment: I'm of the mind that it looks good till you examine it, as you said, only we will see it. We had two rooms of new wood added, and it's nearly perfect. the older floor is where we have bumps, etc. I can live with it. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are standards for the installation of hardwood floors. The national association that is commonly used is the MFMA

https://www.maplefloor.org/TechnicalInfo/Finishes-Sealers.aspx

While their name has “maple” in it, it is also qualified to examine and review other species, such as birch, oak, etc.

I’ve given you a link that shows many members, but I’d scroll to the bottom for MFMA’s main home office in Illinois. I’d start there. They can refer you to a reputable investigator. You’ll probably have to pay to get someone to review the work and prepare a written evaluation.

It looks bad enough to me to require it be re-sanded, re-stained and re-sealed.